# Find the number of subarrays in an array, which has the given sum

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Find the number of subarrays in an array, which has the given sum - here is my attempt but doesn't work properly

```
function getSubArrayCount(arr, sum) {

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var str = [];
        var csum= 0;
        var output = 0;

for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {        
        csum+= arr[j];
        str.push(arr[j]);
        if (csum== sum) {       
              return(str[i]);     
             }
         }
     }
}

console.log(getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5))
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What exactly does not work?

Comment: Welcome to [so], please consider reading the [ask] section of our [help] and [edit] your code accordingly.

Comment: Do you want to count only contiguous subarrays or any subset of elements? e.g. would `[1,2,2]` be a valid subarray to sum up to 5? Would `[2,3]` and `[3,2]` be counted different arrays? What *should* the result be in this case and in others, and what debugging have you done to try to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: This question is non trivial - problem is NP-hard

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 2):

There is also approach with **linear** (depends on map implementation) time complexity requiring O(n) memory.

Store cumulative sums in a map together with counter (how many times some cumulative sum already have been met). At every step check whether current cumulative sum forms needed sum with stored ones.

I'm not familiar with JS but seems this code works

```js
function getSubArrayCount(arr, sum) {
  let map = new Map();
  var cumsum = 0; var cnt = 0;
  map.set(0, 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   cumsum += arr[i];
   if (map.has(cumsum - sum))
      cnt += map.get(cumsum - sum);
   if (map.has(cumsum))
      map.set(cumsum, map.get(cumsum) + 1);
   else  
           map.set(cumsum, 1);
  }
  return cnt;
}

console.log(getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5));   //3
console.log(getSubArrayCount([1,-2,3,-3,4,-2,-1,-1],0));   //5
```

Comment: OP in question not talk about 'contiguous subarray' - but general 'subarray'. For [1,2,3,2,1,8,-3] sum=5 we can find at least 4 subarrays: [1,2,2], [2,3], [8,-3],[1,2,2,3,-3]. But yor result is 3 - wrong

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski As far as I understand, term `subarray` always means contiguous one (like `substring` vs `subsequence`). Of course, we cannot be sure what author meant here.

Comment: yes you have right - so answer for contiguous and general subarrays are valid

Answer (score 1):

A sub array is defined as a contiguous block of the original array. If that is what you are looking for, the below code should work:

```js
function getSubArrayCount(arr, sum) {
  var output = 0, csum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {        
      csum+= arr[j];
      if (csum== sum) {       
        output++;     
      }
    }
    csum= 0;
  }
  
  return output;
}

console.log(getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5));
```

Comment: wrong result: for `ar=[1,2,3,2,1,8,-3,-2], sum=6` your algorithm return `2` - but by hand we can find at least 3 subarrays: `[1,2,3], [1,8,-3], [8,-2], ...`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski [8, -2] is not a sub array since its not contiguous. So 2 is the correct result.

Comment: breaking on `if (csum > sum)` is not good with negative numbers - `1,8,-3` is valid result for sum 6

Comment: @MBo You are right. Thank you. I have updated the snippet.

Comment: Ok - OP don't mention that he talk about 'contiguous subarrays' or general 'subarrays' so answer for both cases are valid

Comment: The answer should be valid for any given input sorry i forgot to add this line

Comment: i want to get getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5) should equal to 3.
getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,4],10) should equal to 1. valid for any input

Answer (score 0):

Finding number of subarrays (general - not contiguous) of given sum is NP-hard problem. So we need to calc sum each of 2^length subarrays. The hardest part of this task is to generate `n`-th subarray - we can do it by

```
let sub= (a,n)=> a.filter((x,i)=> n&(1<<i))
```

The idea behind above code is: if we look on `n` in binary system e.g. `n=1010011b` we can look on it like on flags 1/0 which indicates which element we take to subarray

```
 [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 8,-3 ]    
   1  0  1  0  0  1  1      ->     [1,3,8,-3]
```

So we test i-th bit of number n to filter out i-th element. Corner case: I assume that if sum=0 then we count empty array too. Here is full solution

```js
function getSubArrayCount(a,sum) {
  let r=0, sub= (a,n)=> a.filter((x,i)=> n&(1<<i));
  for(let i=0; i<2**a.length; i++) 
    sub(a,i).reduce((s,c)=>s+c,0)==sum ? r++ : 0;
  return r;
}


console.log('[1,2,3,2,1,8,-3] sum=5 => ', getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5) );
console.log('[1,2,3,4] sum=10       => ', getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,4],10) );
console.log('[1,2,3,-3] sum=3       => ', getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,-3],3) );
```

I assume that subarrays can duplicate. If we not allow subarrays duplication the answer will be more complicated.